# inputting a character string using scanf()

Tags: c, arrays, scanf

I started learning about inputting character strings in C. In the following source code I get a character array of length 5.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    char s1[5];
    printf("enter text:\n");
    scanf("%s",s1);
    printf("\n%s\n",s1);
    return 0;

}
```

when the input is:

1. `1234567891234567`, and I've checked it's working fine up to 16 elements(which I don't understand because it is more than 5 elements).
2. `12345678912345678`, it's giving me an error `segmentation fault: 11` (I gave 17 elements in this case)
3. `123456789123456789`, the error is `Illegal instruction: 4` (I gave 18 elements in this case)

I don't understand why there are different errors. Is this the behavior of `scanf()` or character arrays in C?. The book that I am reading didn't have a clear explanation about these things. FYI I don't know anything about pointers. Any further explanation about this would be really helpful.

Comment: The behavior is *undefined* when the input is more than 4 characters long. *Undefined behavior*  does not mean "has to crash immediately", it means the language has no obligation to do anything in particular.

Comment: but shouldn't it give me an error when the input is more than 5 characters long?

Comment: @buggenerator: This is not a constraint violation, there is no obligation for the compiler to emit a diagnostic message, nor is there a requirement to raise an error at runtime.

Comment: @buggenerator You need to understand if you want to get a message error as soon as you do something wrong, C is not the right language for you. C is for effectiveness, compiler add minimum controls to ensure the most effective program it can generate.

Answer (score 5):

> *Is this the behavior of scanf() or character arrays in C?*

TL;DR - No, you're facing the side-effects of [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

To elaborate, in your case, against a code like

```
 scanf("%s",s1);
```

where you have defined

```
 char s1[5];
```

inputting anything more than 4 `char` will cause your program to venture into invalid memory area (past the allocated memory) which in turn invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Once you hit UB, the behavior of the program cannot be predicted or justified in any way. It can do absolutely anything possible (or even impossible).

There is nothing inherent in the `scanf()` which stops you from reading overly long input and overrun the buffer, you should keep control on the input string scanning by using the field width, like

```
 scanf("%4s",s1);  //1 saved for terminating null
```

Comment: but how is it's fine up to 16 characters and anything more than that giving me errors  and also `Different Errors`?

Comment: read about [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). also check the updated answer for a clarification.

Comment: next time you compile and run, it may accept upto 128 or may crash at the  6 th one, you never know...

Comment: @buggenerator  it not fine up to 16 characters, you just get away with it. As soon as you put more than 4 characters there is some memory overwitten that shouldn't be and this may cause problems later anyway. It's undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

The `scanf` function when reading strings read up to the next white-space (e.g. newline, space, tab etc.), or the "end of file". It has *no* idea about the size of the buffer you provide it.

If the string you read is longer than the buffer provided, then it will write out of bounds, and you will have *undefined behavior*.

The simplest way to stop this is to provide a field length to the `scanf` format, as in

```
char s1[5];
scanf("%4s",s1);
```

Note that I use `4` as field length, as there needs to be space for the string terminator as well.

You can also use the "secure" [`scanf_s`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) for which you need to provide the buffer size as an argument:

```
char s1[5];
scanf_s("%s", s1, sizeof(s1));
```

Comment: i don't mean to be naive here. does that mean the buffer is of 16 characters in this case?

Comment: @buggenerator no the length of the buffer is the length _you_ provide when you declare the variable. So here the length is 5. ( char s1[**5**] )

Comment: @buggenerator The "buffer size" is the size of the array you declare (potentially minus one for the terminator).